# Adjust TCP/UDP Server Runtime

Tags: tcp, server, udp, client, indy

I am using Embarcadero RAD Studio 10.  I am trying to use Indy client/server components in my application.

I want to adjust the TCP/UDP server IP address and port at runtime.

I can see the default settings at design-time:

[image: default option]

I can add entries to the `Bindings` and set the `DefaultPort`.

But, I want to do this while the program is running. I want to set the bindings and port in my UI and push a button to make the server use what I entered.

[image: IP and port bar]

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Bindings` is a collection of `TIdSocketHandle` objects.  Adding a new entry to the collection at design-time is the same as calling the `Bindings.Add()` method at runtime.

`TIdSocketHandle` has `IP` and `Port` properties.  When a `TIdSocketHandle` object is created, its `Port` is initialized with the current value of the `DefaultPort`.

To do what you are asking, simply call `Bindings.Add()` and set the new object's `IP` and `Port` properties.  For example:

Delphi:

```pascal
procedure TMyForm.ConnectButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  LIP: string;
  LPort: TIdPort;
  LBinding: TIdSocketHandle;
begin
  LIP := ServerIPEdit.Text;
  LPort := IntToStr(ServerPortEdit.Text);
  IdTCPServer1.Active := False;
  IdTCPServer1.Bindings.Clear;
  LBinding := IdTCPServer1.Bindings.Add;
  LBinding.IP := LIP;
  LBinding.Port := LPort;
  IdTCPServer1.Active := True;
end;
```

C++:

```cpp
void __fastcall TMyForm::ConnectButtonClick(TObject *Sender);
{
    String LIP = ServerIPEdit->Text;
    TIdPort LPort = IntToStr(ServerPortEdit->Text);
    IdTCPServer1->Active = false;
    IdTCPServer1->Bindings->Clear();
    TIdSocketHandle *LBinding = IdTCPServer1->Bindings->Add();
    LBinding->IP = LIP;
    LBinding->Port = LPort;
    IdTCPServer1->Active = true;
}
```

Same thing with `TIdUDPServer`.

Comment: This code is delphi but i need C++ can you do this with C++?

Comment: @Buraki there is *nothing* in your question that says you are using C++ vs Delphi. Next time, please provide such details, they are important.

Comment: I am sorry that is my fault, next time i will be carefull about this.